# Resize nested divs based on available space

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that sit next to each other, one floated left and one floated right.

Inside the left floated div I have another three nested divs.

I want the nested divs to adjust their width to take up the available space leftover from the right floated div.

How can I make this magic happen?

See codepen example here: http://codepen.io/bennygill/pen/bZkJyV

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-left">
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content.</div>
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content.</div>
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-right">
    Some other divs and tables go in here. The width of this part will exapand based on the dynamic content it contains.
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* Maximum width of container */
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
}

/* Floats div container to the left */
.inner-left {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Floats div container to the right */
.inner-right {
  float: right;
  width: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

/* ??? helpe me position these equally in available space ??? */
.item {
  width: 30%; /* This is wrong because they don't adjust to fill the space next to the blue "inner-right" content*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the few legit use cases for a table. It supports old browsers (flexbox only IE10+) and is fully dynamic.

```css
/* Maximum width of container */
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  display:table;
}

/* Floats div container to the left */
.inner-left {
  vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

/* Floats div container to the right */
.inner-right {
  width: initial;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

/* ??? helpe me position these equally in available space ??? */
.item {
  width: 30%; /* This is wrong because they don't adjust to fill the space next to the blue "inner-right" content*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-left">
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content.</div>
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content.</div>
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-right">
    Some other divs and tables go in here. The width of this part will exapand based on the dynamic content it contains.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This puts everything on the same line, but the red boxes have not shrunk to take up the whatever space is leftover from the blue box. The blue box should be allowed to expand as needed, and the red boxes shrink down to fill the leftover space.

Comment: Actually your solution does work. I just screwed up the order  of inner elements on my live site when testing this. Thanks!

Comment: One problem - it's not mobile responsive. Any way to fix that?

Comment: The table scales with the container and those has a set width. If you you change that in media queries or to % than it is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of display:flex.. Set the `display: flex` for the inner-left class.

```css
/* Maximum width of container */
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
}

/* Floats div container to the left */
.inner-left {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}

/* Floats div container to the right */
.inner-right {
  float: right;
  width: initial;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

/* ??? helpe me position these equally in available space ??? */
.item {
   /* This is wrong because they don't adjust to fill the space next to the blue "inner-right" content*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-left">
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content.</div>
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content.</div>
    <div class="item">Image and text here. I want all three of these to sit next too each other. But their width should adjust too fill the available space next to the blue "inner-right" content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-right">
    Some other divs and tables go in here. The width of this part will exapand based on the dynamic content it contains.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I too thought `flex` was the answer, but unfortunately not. This solution does not shrink down the red "item" boxes so they sit next to the blue "inner-right box".

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use the CSS `calc()` function together with the `max-width` property to determine the maximum width, the pickle here was your border, which took too much space.

```
/* Maximum width of container */
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
}

/* Floats div container to the left */
.inner-left {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 75%
}

/* Floats div container to the right */
.inner-right {
  float: left;
  max-width: calc(25% - 10px);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

/* ??? helpe me position these equally in available space ??? */
.item {
  width: calc(33% - 10px); /* This is wrong because they don't adjust to fill the space next to the blue "inner-right" content*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

[More info on](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/calc) `calc()`
[More info on](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) `max-width`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The red "inner-right" box should be allowed to expand as needed (no max-width) and the red "item" boxes do not shrink down as needed. But I have never heard of  the calc() function, so thanks for that!